# Copy state to clipboard in react callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react callback that activates on a button press:

```
const handleExport = () => {
    let dummy = document.createElement("input");
    dummy.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(state));
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
    addToast('Copied config to clipboard.', { appearance: 'success'});
};
```

But when I execute it, it doesn't copy to my clipboard.   I queried `document.queryCommandSupported('copy')` in the console and it returns true, so why is it not copying my text?

Comment: Did you try navigator.clipboard.writeText('Text to be copied'); before executing the copy command?

Comment: I found [clipboard-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-polyfill) extremely useful when creating a copy-to-clipboard component. Uses, I believe, `navigator.clipboard` under the hood (*and provides fallback solutions for multiple platforms*).